# Is it possible to find the difference between two sets in set-builder form?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For instance, if there is a set $A$ in set-builder form and a set $B$ in set-builder form, what will be the difference $A-B$?

For example, if $A=\{x  \in  \mathbb R: 0<x<3\}$ and $B=\{x  \in\mathbb  R: 1\le x\le 5\}$, then how would I find $A-B$ or $B-A$? Is it necessary to first convert them to roster form and then solve them? Is their any way, so that the sets can be directly solved in set-builder form? However here it is about real numbers and you cannot list all of the real numbers. It's in the interval, but it is possible for, sets like where $x \in \mathbb N$ or $x \in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result $A-B$ can be written as, in set-builder form, $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid 0<x<3 \wedge  \neg (1\leq x\leq 5)\}$. Other set operations such as union, intersection, and complement can also be done in this way. However, when you are going to further use this set, it's kind of obliged for you to solve the condition and write down precisely the elements.